# How to change font of MFC PropertySheet

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have a class derived from CPropertySheet. Please let me know how can I change the font of this propertysheet tab along with fonts in all pages. Currently they used system font only.

Also I would like the dialog box to come up at specific location on screen and remain there only. Please let me know how can I change location of propertysheet dialog when it is getting initialised.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CPropertySheet inherits the SetFont method from CWnd. You could call this method from CPropertySheet::OnInitDialog. Do the same thing in the pages to set their font.

Comment: It has no effect. I tried it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984753(v=vs.71).aspx#_core_cpropertysheet_always_changes_its_font_to_the_default_font

Comment: This used to work until the implementation switched to using the built-in common controls, MFC 4.0. A bit of hard googling reveals some painful mechanisms for accomplishing it, none of which look particularly fun. The first link here: http://bit.ly/1B39hqI looks promising

Comment: You may have to call `SetFont` on the embedded pages too.